# Application Migration to Dapper.net from EF4

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4, dapper

I am working on a large WPF application with Entity framework4 now client is asking to migrate application from EF4 to Dapper.net. I am not sure about feasibility & business gain of this migration task as following features of EF4 are missing in Dapper:

- Change tracking
- Lazy-loading
- Eager fetching
- Cascades
- Identity map
- Unit of work tracking

please suggest me on this or if other better micro ORM exists for WPF applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF4 and dapper are different tools with different goals and different features. Indeed, it is pretty common to see dapper and tools like EF working side by side (sometimes even against the same object-model) - particularly when you aren't *using* all the things you've listed in the bullets; for example, a lot of "display" code (showing pages to the user, etc) tends to not use those things. For read-only code, it can sometimes be embarrassingly simple to switch in a dapper implementation - just write some SQL and away you go.

However! When it comes to code that *does* use the features you've mentioned, this is a much more fundamental change; it isn't really "migrate" so much as "re-implement". Without things like change tracking, your own code would need to be a bit clearer about what operations each process is performing. This is *actually* a good thing, IMO, but is not trivial to retrofit into an existing codebase. If starting from *scratch* (or: new tables etc in an existing model), it is generally very easy.

Personally, the approach I would take here is *first* to look at your key data fetch operations (especially high frequency, complex query, or large volume) - and consider whether they could be replaced with dapper-based read operations; *especially* if read-only. You can probably get some huge wins with minimal work. Profiling would be important, and tools like mini-profiler might help. I would *not* personally start ripping out an existing, working data layer for the rest of it - that seems like inventing work for the sake of it; and it will be complicated (swapping out an ORM is *not* a trivial thing).

I *would*, however, put some serious thought into updating to a more recent version of EF ;p

(oh, and if it matters: I'm the primary author and maintainer of dapper)

Comment: Thanks for reply. You mean to say that only for read only views we should use dapper & let dapper & EF work side by side. I do need concurrency management & changetracking in my application. pls suggest.

Comment: @user1103378 to be clear: I'm not saying dapper should only be for read-only views; heck, virtually all of our **new code** that does data changes has used dapper for the last few years; what I am saying is that *changing between* ORM-based change-tracked writes, versus micro-ORM explicit writes (regardless of which ORM / micro-ORM) - is not trivial. As such, I wouldn't choose to do so casually, or on whim. If it absolutely has to happen: then sure, it can be done - but it could be quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the crucial question is why your client want you to migrate this project to another framework.

If she wants you to perform this migration because of poor performance of some functionalities or modules then you could take Marc's approach and migrate only critical parts of your system.

In some of my company's projects we use Dapper side by side with full-blown NHibernate stuff and it really works. Especially in reporting and batch processing when you probably want to call stored procedures instead of simple CRUD operations.

If you decide to follow this path, I'd suggest you to consider using "Unit of work" pattern to enable EF 
and Dapper to work on same database connection (I've [bloged](http://mkarczewski.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/entity-framework-transactions-multiple-contexts-and-mixing-with-ado-net) about this matter some time ago).

Of course you have to keep in your mind technical differences like that Dapper (in opposite to "full-blown" ORMs like EF or NH) does not have concept of session and "dirty" objects modified by EF should be read by Dapper only after flushing changes to DB.